# Crystal Report's Report Viewer "A statement is expected here"

Tags: crystal-reports, basic

I am using Crystal Reports 2016 and am trying to get a QR code solution to work in Report Viewer. The QR code prints flawlessly with the packaged QR font in the Crystal Reports editor, but in Report viewer, it throws an "A statement is expected here" error (see screenshot).[image]

The code I am using is the QR solution vendor's code inside a formula field with Basic syntax:

```
ConnectCodeClassQRCodeEncode ({search_loc.LOC_DESC},"L",8)
Dim x As Number
Dim Result As String
For x = 1 To ConnectCodeClassQRCodeNumBlocks()
    Result=Result + ConnectCodeClassQRCodeGetBlocks(x)
Next x
formula = Result
```

Is Report Viewer expecting Crystal Syntax instead of Basic Syntax? Or is Report Viewer not knowing where to find the ConnectCodeClassQRCodeEncode function?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the UFL providing that function on the target machine.